# How to calculate average from Collection of HashMap<String, Double>

Tags: java, hashmap, multimap

I have a Collection of HashMap<String, Duble> which I am getting from multimap. I want to calculate the average on Maps values and calculate which Map key is having minimum average. The data looks like that:

```
HashMap<A1, 2.0>
HashMap<A2, 1.0>
HashMap<A1, 3.0>
HashMap<A2, 1.0>
```

I am not getting the idea. Can someone give me a hint?

Adding some more data which show why I am using MultiMap.

```
{‘Gateway’:’ G1’, ‘Device’: ‘D1’,’position’:{‘rssi’: 1}},
{‘Gateway’:’ G2’, ‘Device’: ‘D1’,’position’:{‘rssi’: 3}},
{‘Gateway’:’ G1’, ‘Device’: ‘D1’,’position’:{‘rssi’: 2}},
{‘Gateway’:’ G2’, ‘Device’: ‘D1’,’position’:{‘rssi’: 5}},
{‘Gateway’:’ G1’, ‘Device’: ‘D1’,’position’:{‘rssi’: 4}},
{‘Gateway’:’ G2’, ‘Device’: ‘D1’,’position’:{‘rssi’: 6}},
..
{‘Gateway’:’ G1’, ‘Device’: ‘D2’,’position’:{‘rssi’: 3}},
{‘Gateway’:’ G2’, ‘Device’: ‘D2’,’position’:{‘rssi’: 2}},
```

Actually, this is a series of data coming to my endpoint, I need to calculate Which device is staying more at which Gateway. First I need to add Devices into MultiMap and then Gateway with position into Map.
In the end I want to calculate the average like that:

```
D1-> G1: {1,2,4} => 7/3 = 2.3 
D1-> G2: {3,5,6} => 14/3 = 4.6
```

Comment: Stream trough each map and collect the doubles and calculate the average.

Comment: How and where to link the key after calculating the average?

Comment: The key would have nothing to do with the average would it?

Comment: @g00se Well, this is why I am using HashMap, I need to find the Key and then decide which Key in the collection of HashMap has a lower average.

Comment: What do you mean by "key in the collection of HashMap"?  What kind of collection is it?  Do you actually have a HashMap of HashMaps, or something like that?

Comment: So the average in your particular case is 1.75. How does the key fit in with that value?

Comment: No, I want to calculate the average on each Key, for example, A1 average is (2.0+3.0)/2= 2.5, A2 average is (1.0,1.0)/2=1. 
After that method will return A2 in response because it has a lower average.

Comment: If you have one HashMap as shown, then you **don't have** two instances of the A1 (or A2) key.   Problem solved!

Comment: @undefinedsymbol Well, this is by design as I mentioned in my question that I am also using MultiMap.

Comment: So it looks like you've separated out the multimap into separate maps. If that's the case, why are you not calculating the average directly on the multimap? That would seem to make more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your collection of maps is something similar to this:

```
List<Map<String, Double>> mapList = List.of(
        Map.of("A1", 2.0),
        Map.of("A2", 1.0),
        Map.of("A1", 3.0),
        Map.of("A2", 1.0));
```

You can just stream over the list (collection), stream over the entries of each map flatmaping to a stream of entries, collect to a new map grouping by key and averaging value, stream over the resulting map and find the min using a comparator by value:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

....



Entry<String, Double> entryWithMinAvg =
        mapList.stream()
               .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, Collectors.averagingDouble(Entry::getValue)))
               .entrySet()
               .stream()
               .min(Entry.comparingByValue())
               .get();

System.out.println(entryWithMinAvg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward multi-map implementation using standard Java collections is a `Map<K,List<V>>` - i.e. a map from each key to a list of values for that key. It is relatively trivial to add to it using

```
Map<String,List<Double>> multimap;
multimap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
```

Finding the key with the minimum average is also trivial using a comparator to compare the averages:

```
Comparator<String> compareAverageKeys = Comparator.comparingDouble(
    k -> multimap.get(k).stream().mapToDouble(v -> v).average().get());
multimap.keys().stream().min(compareAverageKeys);
```

If your only reason for creating the collection is to find the average then you could just keep the stats rather than the keys:

```
Map<String,DoubleSummaryStatistics> stats;

stats.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new DoubleSummaryStatistics()).add(value);
```

Then finding the key with the minimum is much simpler and more efficient:

```
stats.keys().stream().min(Comparator.comparingDouble(k -> stats.get(k).getAverage());
```